# Push to npm repo while not owner

Tags: node.js, npm

I need to use a npm package that is incompatible with my current node version. I go to the github that hosts the package. Someone posted a fix, but they haven't merged it in and pushed it to npm. I was wondering if there was a way to download the fix myself and push it to npm.

Thanks

Comment: Find the fork that has the patch and clone it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't publish to the original module's npm registry entry unless the original owner gives you permission. You could publish your own fork however, under a different name on npm.

Also, you can install modules from github and refer to github repos in your `dependencies` in your `package.json`. This way you don't need to publish a new module on npm.